If a k-arc exists in a projective plane of order q, then k ≤ q + 2. If equality holds, q must be even.
A projective plane of order  q  is a $(q^2+q + 1,q + 1,1)-BIBD$. A k-arc refers to a set of k points in the projective plane such that no three points belong to the same block.
I have currently proven that $ k \leq q + 2 $. Using a proof by contradiction, suppose there exists a k-arc where  $k \geq q + 3 $. Then, in this set of k points, each pair of points must appear in the same block, and these blocks must all be different. Therefore, each point in this set of k points must appear in at least  $k - 1 \geq q + 2$blocks, which contradicts the parameter  b = q + 1  of the symmetric BIBD.
At the moment, I am unable to prove that when  $k = q + 2$ ,  q  must be even.
